# Sending apns using erlang

Tags: ssl, erlang, apple-push-notifications, ejabberd

this is part of code I am using to send apns.

```
  Options = case Password of
      undefined ->
          [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Keyfile}, {mode, binary}];
      _ ->
        [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Keyfile}, {password, Password}, {mode, binary}]
  end,
  case ssl:connect(Address, Port, Options, ?Timeout) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            PayloadBin = list_to_binary(Payload),
            PayloadLength = size(PayloadBin),
            TokenNum = erlang:binary_to_integer(Token, 16),
            TokenBin = <<TokenNum:32/integer-unit:8>>,
            Packet = <<
                0:8,
                32:16/big,
                TokenBin/binary,
                PayloadLength:16/big,
                PayloadBin/binary
            >>,
            ssl:send(Socket, Packet),
            ssl:close(Socket),
            ?DEBUG("mod_apns: Successfully sent payload to the APNS server", []),
            ok;
        {error, Reason} ->
            ?ERROR_MSG("mod_apns: Unable to connect:~p to the APNS server ~p: ~p", [Options, Address, Reason]),
            Reason
    end
```

But I get this error:

```
Unable to connect:[{certfile,<<"/etc/certificates/myCer.pem">>},{keyfile,<<"/etc/certificates/myKey.pem">>},{mode,binary}] to the APNS server <<"gateway.push.apple.com">>: {options,{socket_options,[{mode,binary}]}}
```

This is an ejabberd module and same code works in ejabberd 17.04 but not in 17.06.
Certificates and keys are valid and as I said I can get apns using same erlang module with older version of ejabberd.
I am new to erlang and I don't understand the error message `({options,{socket_options,[{mode,binary}]}})`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I added more code..
When I change {mode, binary} to {mode, Mode :: binary | list} I get syntax error

Comment: Possibly: `{mode, Mode :: binary | list} => 
Received Packet is delivered as defined by Mode.`  So...the received packet is either an erlang binary type or a list.

Comment: The option would be specified as `{mode, binary}` or `{mode, list}`.  In the _specification_ I posted, the placeholder variable's name is Mode, and it can have the values `binary | list`.

Comment: I initially has used {mode, binary} but I tried {mode, list} as well and still getting error.
When i use {mode, list} the error changes to :
{options,{socket_options,[{mode,list}]}}

Comment: Yeah, I think your error message is just giving you a dump of the options.  Is there more to the error message?

Comment: If there is I am not sure how to check! I just simply print out Reason after ssl:connect goes to {error, Reason} -> section

Comment: It looks like a similar problem was discussed here: https://github.com/mrDoctorWho/ejabberd_mod_apns/issues/2

Comment: No it's not the same problem. I asked that question last year but this issue is something totally new. But thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was sending binary instead of list:

```
mod_opt_type(address) -> fun binary_to_list/1;
mod_opt_type(port) -> fun(I) when is_integer(I) -> I end;
mod_opt_type(certfile) -> fun binary_to_list/1;
mod_opt_type(keyfile) -> fun binary_to_list/1;
```